# Passing javascript variables from controller to partial file in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJs. I have put a url value in the scope variable inside a controller. This value should be used in the partial file corresponding to the controller inside a javascript function. How can I achieve this in AngularJs.

Code snippet is given below for reference:
Config code:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
   when('/state-details/:id',
   {
      controller:'controllers.StateDetailsCtrl',
      templateUrl:'/partials/state-details.html'
   })
   .... More routes defined below...
```

Inside the controller:

```
controllers.StateDetailsCtrl= function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
  $scope.testURL='http://www.google.com'
  .... More values set in the scope..
```

Inside the `state-details` partial file:

```
<script>
// how to get the value of the testURL defined in the scope?
</script>
```

Please let me know how to get this working?

Comment: Set an `ng-controller='StateDetailsCtrl'` on your html block and then you can call your scope variable with just `{{testURL}}`

Comment: What are you looking to do inside of those `<script>` tags?

Comment: I want to access the testURL variable set inside the controller. How to get this?

Comment: If i add the `ng-controller='StateDetailsCtrl'` inside the html block and try to access the `testURL` inside the script tag I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add additional javascript into a partial html file, then it just like screams to use a directive.

There you can inherit the whole ctrl scope or create a isolated scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive